# Не удаётся получить NextIP с метода NextIPAddress

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address

```
class IpAddress
{
    public readonly IPAddress FirstIp;
    public readonly IPAddress LastIp;


    public IpAddress(string firstIp,string lastIp)
    {
        FirstIp = IPAddress.Parse(firstIp);
        LastIp = IPAddress.Parse(lastIp);
    }




    public IEnumerable<IPAddress> NextIpAddress()
    {

        var firstIpAddressAsBytesArray = FirstIp.GetAddressBytes();
        var lastIpAddressAsBytesArray = LastIp.GetAddressBytes();
        Array.Reverse(firstIpAddressAsBytesArray);
        Array.Reverse(lastIpAddressAsBytesArray);
        var firstIpAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(firstIpAddressAsBytesArray, 0);
        var lastIpAddressAsInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(lastIpAddressAsBytesArray, 0);
        for (var i = firstIpAddressAsInt; i <= lastIpAddressAsInt; i++)
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
            yield return  new IPAddress(new[] { bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0] });

        }

    }

}
```

(foreach не предлагать) в данном случае такой метод работает

хочется чтобы при нажатии на кнопку метод выдавал следующий IP Address и записывал его в файл.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var b = a.NextIpAddress().GetEnumerator();
     b.MoveNext();
     Log.WriteToFile("LogFile.txt",b.Current.ToString());
}
```

в данном коде записывается только первый IP Address
при повторном нажатии записывается тоже первый IP Address (хотя MoveNext есть) а хотелось уже следующий из диапазона.
Уже все перепробовал, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вы каждый раз создаете `b` - вот оно и начинает отсчет с начала. Уберите создание `b` из метода (сделайте переменную полем, а заполнение делайте где-нибудь еще) - тогда метод `b.MoveNext()` и будет работать как вы хотите.

Кстати, не забывайте проверять возвращаемое значение, чтобы не пропустить конец последовательности.

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerator<IPAddress> b = IpRangeAddress.NextIpAddress().GetEnumerator();

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        b.MoveNext();
        Log.WriteToFile(Log.TypeOfLog.Request,IpRangeAddress.CurrentIp.ToString() );

    }
```

Инициализировал приватное поле потом при каждом нажатии переходит на следующий. Спасибо за ответ, я сразу не догадался.